# Can Material-UI and reactstrap co-exist in the same Reactjs application?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I have a Reactjs app that I'd like to convert from react-strap to Materials-UI.  My question is, can I have them both including in the app at the same time? This would allow me to convert a component at a time. The other option is to create it from scratch, which I would hopefully avoid.

Another concern, is it possible that I'll somehow corrupt the application by importing the Materials-UI dependency? And would restoring from git be enough to eliminate the problem?

The main reason for doing this is I've had a difficult time trying to create a dropdown box in a form in reactstrap, despite my best efforts. Materials-UI seems to be a widely-used and supported library, with a nice set of components, including dropdown.